# How to get users having data available for particular date and no data for others dates

Tags: sql-server, group-by, sql-server-2016

I have a table containing available records of users from which I have to prioritize users having last 5th day data only from current date, then users with 4th or 5th day data only from current, then users with 3rd, 4th or 5th day data only and so on.

I have grouped last 5 days data by user and date and get the below result

```
User       Date         Available records

1. 1001    31-08-2019   2
2. 1001    30-08-2019   3
3. 1002    27-08-2019   1
4. 1002    28-08-2019   3
5. 1003    27-08-2019   2
```

Now I need to select those users only having data available for last 5th day only. For eg. if last 5th day date is 27 from current, then I need to get

1003 user only. After that I need to get user with last 4th or 5th day data only i.e. 1002.

I have tried the same with below query but didn't get desired result

```
SELECT * 
FROM AgentCallDateWiseCalls
WHERE (CAST(CallDate AS DATE) <= CAST(GETDATE() - 5 AS DATE) 
  AND CallsAvailable >= 0)
  AND (CAST(CallDate AS DATE) > CAST(GETDATE() - 5 AS DATE) AND CallsAvailable = 0)
```

Where 5 will be variable.

Comment: by "last 5th day" do you mean the last 5 days or only the date that is 5 days prior?

Comment: only the date last 5 days prior

Comment: look into DATEDIFF https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
SELECT a1.* 
FROM [AgentCallDateWiseCalls] a1
LEFT JOIN   (
                SELECT DISTINCT [User] 
                FROM    [AgentCallDateWiseCalls] 
                WHERE   (CAST([CallDate] AS DATE) > CAST(GETDATE() - 5 AS DATE) 
                        AND [CallsAvailable] > 0)
            )   a2 ON a1.[User] = a2.[User]
WHERE   (CAST(a1.[CallDate] AS DATE) <= CAST(GETDATE() - 5 AS DATE) 
        AND a1.[CallsAvailable] > 0) 
        AND a2.[User] IS NULL
```

this query select all users that having record with CallsAvailable > 0 in last 5th day and no records in 1st to 4th last days.